Create contour lines (interpolate from existing vector data)
I am a QGIS user.
I have vector lines (shapefiles) with 0, 5, 10, etc. values and I want to create (interpolate) contour lines between these lines with values 1,2,3,4, 6,7,8,0, etc.
How can I do this?

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. This is not a trivial task. I suggest you seek a tutorial to explain the options and ways forward.

see https://www.geodose.com/2018/05/how-to-create-contour-lines-in-qgis.html
